# ASP.NET MVC -> WCF -> NHibernate, how to efficiently update entity with data from viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, nhibernate, automapper

A week back, I had an ASP.NET MVC application that called on a logical POCO service layer to perform business logic against entities.  One approach I commonly used was to use AutoMapper to map a populated viewmodel to an entity and call update on the entity (pseudo code below).

```
MyEntity myEntity = myService.GetEntity(param);

Mapper.CreateMap<MyEntityVM, MyEntity>();
Mapper.Map(myEntityVM, myEntity);

this.myService.UpdateEntity(myEntity);
```

The update call would take an instance of the entity and, through a repository, call NHibernate's Update method on the entity.

Well, I recently changed my logical service layer into WCF Web Services.  I've noticed that the link NHibernate makes with an entity is now lost when the entity is sent from the service layer to my application.  When I try to operate against the entity in the update method, things are in NHibernate's session that shouldn't be and vice-versa - it fails complaining about nulls on child identifiers and such.

So my question...

What can I do to efficiently take input from my populated viewmodel and ultimately end up modifying the object through NHibernate?

- Is there a quick fix that I can apply with NHibernate?
- Should I take a different approach in conveying the changes from the application to the service layer?

EDIT:

The best approach I can think of right now, is to create a new entity and map from the view model to the new entity (including the identifier).  I would pass that to the service layer where it would retrieve the entity using the repository, map the changes using AutoMapper, and call the repository's update method.  I will be mapping twice, but it might work (although I'll have to exclude a bunch of properties/children in the second mapping).

Answer (score 1):

No quick fix. You've run into the change tracking over the wire issue.  AFAIK NHibernate has no native way to handle this.

These may help:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=989106

http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2007/05/09/remoting-using-wcf-and-nhibernate/

In a nutshell your two options are to adjust your service to send state change information over the Nhibernate can read or load the objects, apply the changes and then save in your service layer.

Don't be afraid of doing a select before an update inside your service.  This is good practice anyway to prevent concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but I wanted to pass along information on a [quick fix](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2009/11/nhibernate-feature-saveorupdatecopy.html) with NHibernate.

From NHibernate.xml...

```
<member name="M:NHibernate.ISession.SaveOrUpdateCopy(System.Object)">
    <summary>
    Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same
    identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with 
    the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the 
    given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, save it and 
    return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance
    does not become associated with the session.
    </summary>
    <param name="obj">a transient instance with state to be copied</param>
    <returns>an updated persistent instance</returns>
</member>
```

It's working although I haven't had time to examine the database calls to see if it's doing exactly what I expect it to do.